# How to change the language of liveAnnouncer

Tags: angular, angular-material, accessibility

Is it possible to change language of liveAnnouncer? It only reads text in English but I would like it to read Finnish text in Finnish. I have imported live announcer with: `import { LiveAnnouncer } from '@angular/cdk/a11y';` and it does not seem to take any language parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If your entire page is in Finnish, just add the `lang='fi'` attribute to the root `<html>` element. This attribute is required by WCAG, so it's good practice to include it, no matter what.

If only part of the page is in Finnish, you'll have to add the attribute to that part. In this case, I suppose it should be added to the region itself.

CDK docs do not mention anything, but you can add the `lang` attribute to any element. I assume that if you can identify/select the live region (look in the generated DOM for clues about how you can select it), then you will be able to add this attribute.

It might be as simple as

```
document.querySelector("*[aria-live]").setAttribute("lang", "fi");
```

You'd have to make sure that the element had been added to the DOM before this runs. (I am not completely on top of the exact sequence of events in angular, but I think this is possible).

Of course, this is a hack/heresy according to the angular approach.

However, there are apparently some outstanding bugs on at least two leading screen readers (NVDA and VoiceOver) where the lang attribute is not always respected in live regions. These are not good reasons to omit the attribute, since the bugs will one day get fixed. If you've done your work right, you will inherit the fix when Apple and NVDA get around to it.

https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/issues/4396

Comment: I have put lang="fi" to page root. It changes dynamically, when user changes the language of the page. It works on other places but not with liveAnnouncer. LiveAnnouncer creates a box for the text in the bottom of the page, but reads it only in English.

Comment: I did some digging into this issue, and it appears that none(!) of the leading screen readers on any platform (NVDA, JAWS, VoiceOver...) respect the lang attribute in live regions today. There are other places where they fail, too, such as aria-label and aria-roledescription. So I don't think that LiveAnnouncer is the culprit here. The best you can do for now is just make sure that the attribute is set correctly in your markup and (ideally) report the issue to the screen reader vendor(s)